# Why won't this button's onclick parameter work?

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<input type="button" value="Accept Contract" class="button" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this contract?')) window.open('actionurl.php');">
```

Simple enough, why won't it work?  It doesn't bring up a confirm box at all.

Comment: Look at your javascript errors. maybe other things have failed prior to this

Comment: This should work per se. Paste some more markup / code. Also, isn't your browser maybe just blocking the new window as a popup?

Comment: @Brenden - Despite my warnings otherwise, you may want to try Bane and  Mark's suggestions. They are cleaner solutions, and if they do solve your problem, it's perfectly acceptable to accept those as the correct answer. Also, it's helpful to know what errors you're getting in Firebug or your Chrome Developer Toolbar. Without knowing this information, it's difficult to ascertain what is causing your problem.

Comment: works fine on IE9 - it could be that you have other JS code running and it got terminated before it reached to your simple onclick call.

Comment: Do confirm boxes work for you in your browser in other areas of your code Brenden? That would be helpful to know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked well here. However, try this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('confirmButton').onclick = function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this contract?'))
        window.open('actionurl.php');
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Accept Contract" class="button" id="confirmButton">
```

Comment: I really like this approach as it keeps all JavaScript completely out of the HTML elements/attributes and keeps JavaScript where it belongs; however, this still doesn't address the question of why the original approach doesn't work.

Comment: I like this as well, turns out I removed a php reference to post it here, but in the php reference there was a missing quote, however, this answer led me to finding that and I now used this approach anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather make a separate function for that.

```
<script>
function bla()
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this contract?'))
        window.open('actionurl.php');
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Accept Contract" class="button" onclick="bla();">
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but it doesn't explain why the op's code doesn't work. It clearly looks like it should work.

Comment: Well, it does solve his problem, and I see nothing wrong with his code, so I posted this...

Comment: We're not sure what the problem is yet without seeing error messages from a debugger. My advice is be careful posting solutions that don't exactly answer or address the question. Again, this is a good suggestion, but just be aware that it may not actually solve the problem if there is something else in the OP's code -- not shown -- that is causing other JavaScript to not fire.

Answer (score 2):

Tested it and work fine, checked it yourself

http://jsfiddle.net/XSTCm/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B5MxX/

If it doesn't work there, then it might have to do with browser compatibility of confirm